# Implementing lazy load strategy for dynamically generated Airflow DAGs and caching between master DAG

Tags: airflow

I am currently working on implementing a lazy load strategy for dynamically generating Airflow DAGs in my project. The goal is to use YAML files as configuration definitions for the DAGs, dynamically load them during runtime, and cache the generated DAG instances to improve performance. However, I have the limitation of not being able to make changes to the underlying Airflow environment itself; I can only make changes to the content of the project's repository.

To achieve this, I have developed a solution where the YAML files are parsed and converted into DAG instances, which are then added to the Airflow global `DagBag` for scheduling. This approach enables the automatic creation and scheduling of DAGs based on the configuration defined in the YAML files.

The specific requirements for this implementation are as follows:

1. Load the DAGs from YAML files and convert them into Airflow DAG instances.
2. Cache the generated DAG instances between master DAG runs to avoid unnecessary reprocessing.
3. During each master DAG run, only generate DAG instances from the YAML files that have been newly created or modified since the last run.
4. Add both newly created/modified DAGs and the cached DAGs to the global `DagBag` for scheduling.
5. Avoid duplications by replacing the cached instance of a DAG if the corresponding YAML file has been modified.

The challenge I am facing is that I cannot make changes to the underlying Airflow environment configuration or infrastructure. I only have control over the content of the project's repository. Therefore, I cannot configure additional tools like Redis or Memcached for caching purposes.

I have attempted to implement a solution using a combination of YAML parsing, caching in Airflow Variables, and selective DAG loading based on file modification times. However, I am encountering challenges with YAML parsing and constructing Airflow DAG objects using custom constructors.

Given these limitations, I would appreciate any recommendations or insights on alternative approaches or libraries that can help achieve the lazy load strategy and DAG caching without requiring changes to the underlying Airflow environment. Any suggestions to improve the efficiency and reliability of the current implementation within the project's repository would be highly valuable.

Thank you for your assistance!